# Print global colors into a text string in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, branding, illustrator-scripting

You know what would be super nice?

If there would be a function to link global colors to text strings.
So if I create a CI/CD Manual and I change a color. The codes would update automaticaly.

Do you get what I mean? is this somehow possible:

[image]

This would be mad

Comment: Well, you could use the C++ API and make a effects node that does this, yes.

Comment: I mean without getting a degree in computer science ;)

Comment: well the degree in computer science does not write the code. No no other way. There are no events in the scripting API's Best a script can do is update when you call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Illustrator does not expose a scene graph to users or even the script layer. Scripts are meant to do a thing and exit, there is very limitted amount of event hooks that you could depend on. So your script can not just hang around making changes when something happens.

Illustrator does, however expose a limited graph to the C++ API for faclitating effects. THis layer does trigger on color update so nothing stops you form makeing an effect for this purpose.